# Meaning of Proust's "Real life, life at last laid bare and illuminated ... is literature"

Tags: meaning, french-language, marcel-proust, in-search-of-lost-time

Marcel Proust writes in [*The Past Recaptured*](https://archive.org/details/isbn_0394706005/page/150/mode/2up) (English translation by Andreas Mayor, 1970):

> Real life, life at last laid bare and illuminated—the only life in consequence which can be said to be really lived—is literature

What is the meaning of this quote?

Comment: La vraie vie, la vie enfin découverte et éclaircie, la seule vie par conséquent pleinement vécue, c'est la littérature.

Comment: My interpretation: Life is only fully lived if it can be well-remembered and fully examined, and the only way of doing that is through literature.

Comment: I think Ian Patterson gives a signifcantly better translation in his translation, *Time Regained:* "Real life, life finally uncovered and clarified, the only life in consequence lived to the full, is literature."

Comment: And to put it into context, the following lines in Patterson's translation: are "Real life, life finally uncovered and clarified, the only life in consequence lived to the full, is literature. Life in this sense dwells within all ordinary people as much as in the artist. But they do not see it because they are not trying to shed light on it. And so their past is cluttered with countless photographic negatives, which continue to be useless because their intellect has never 'developed' them."